# Button is still working even when removeFromParent() in Swift SpriteKit is called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In the code below if I press the `removeButton` the button would disappear but it's still working. Maybe I should make the `if` statement false but I don't know how.

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

    var button : SKSpriteNode!
    var removeButton : SKSpriteNode!
    var image : SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) { 
        createButton()
        createRemoveButton()
    }

    func createButton() {
        button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button")
        button.position = CGPoint(x: -300,y: 0)
        self.addChild(button)
    }

    func createRemoveButton() {
        removeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "removeButton")
        removeButton.position = CGPoint(x: 300,y: 0)
        self.addChild(removeButton)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        if button.contains(touchLocation) {
            image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
            image.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 300)
            self.addChild(image)
        }
        if removeButton.contains(touchLocation) {
            button.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you remove a node in SpriteKit.  You should go back to a book.

Comment: @ElTomato that is an unconstructive and in necessary comment. If you have an idea that the OP is doing it wrong you should show them the proper way of doing it. Saying it is wrong go get a book is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and what it takes to retain an instance.

In your case you are retaining button, which means it does not delete from memory.

Now when you remove the button from the parent,  the button's frame is still exactly the same, the only thing different is `button.parent` is now `nil`

When you call `button.contains(touchLocation)`, this is going to pass because you are not concerned with whether or not button is on the scene,  all you are doing is checking if the `touchLocation` is within the `frame` of the button.

The quickest fix is to check the parent:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)
    if button.parent == self && button.contains(touchLocation) {
        image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
        image.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 300)
        self.addChild(image)
    }
    if removeButton.contains(touchLocation) {
        button.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

In reality though, you need to learn how to better manage your resources.  I would recommend trying to find tutorials about how ARC works.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal because you dont use the good button. You use `button` instead of `removeButton`.

You should do:

```
if removeButton.contains(touchLocation) {
   removeButton.removeFromParent()
}
```

Now it should work correctly

Comment: pretty sure you are interpreting this your own way. (not saying that his question is great)...but the opening line of his question clearly states "if I press the removeButton the button would disappear". He has stated it like it was coded, albeit very poor naming choices